# How can I connect ray to laravel sail docker container using the forge user?

Tags: docker, ssh-keys, ray, laravel-sail

I am trying to connect my ray application to my project that is running on a docker container. I am using a Macbook Pro. I've followed the instructions given at https://spatie.be/docs/ray/v1/environment-specific-configuration/docker.

I've also followed all of the ray installation instructions, by entering

```
composer require spatie/laravel-ray
```

setting my ray.php's remote_path to

```
'/var/www/html'
```

and its local_path to

```
'/Users/me/test-projects/project/'
```

I've also updated my project's docker-compose.yaml to include the extra_hosts: line that https://spatie.be/docs/ray/v1/environment-specific-configuration/docker recommends.

```
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-8000}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        extra_hosts:
          - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

I do have custom ssh entries if that matters. I have a id_rsa_personal key and an id_rsa_work rsa key instead of just an id_rsa key that ray's "servers" configuration looks for by default, but even when changing the "private key path" to an existing private key, I get

```
Error: Error invoking remote method 'connectSsh': Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:22
```

If there is anyone out there that has any ideas of why I would not be able to make ray connect to the docker instance, I'd be very grateful.

**update**

After some digging and die'ing through ray's source code, I'm finding that when ray tries to cURL to my host machine, it is getting : Could not resolve host: host.docker.internal. I don't know why this is, because, as I said, I do have extra_hosts: - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" set in my docker-compose.yaml file.

Comment: At this point, I still have no good answer, but as a workaround, I can get Ray to work by manually inputting my computers IP address into the ray.php file with 
    'host' => '{ip address here}',